# Convert 1D index from blocked data to 1D index of whole data

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing

I have volume (3D image) divided into blocks 16x16x16. Whole volume is 128x128x128. Data are stored in linear memory. For every block, i store start index within linear memory of whole data. 
Now, I need to recalculate index from 16x16x16 block to index of 128x128x128 data. Every block is iterated with index 0, 1, 2, 3, ....4096 and I need to change this to global linear index.

Eg.:

```
Block 1, index [2] => convert to index [18]
Block 1, index [18] => convert to index [146]
```

2D example is ilustrated in image. I want to convert red dot (index 135) to index within whole image. Meaning it will be 1040 + something. Numbers in block corners are linear offsets within image.
I need formula for 3D data.
[image: 2D example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coordinates in block: (Index div 256, (Index div 16) mod 16, Index mod 16)

Coordinates of the block origin: (16 * (Block div 64), 16 * ((Block div 8) mod 8), 16 * (Block mod 8))

Coordinates in the whole volume: (16 * (Block div 64) + (Index div 256),(16 * ((Block div 8) mod 8) + ((Index div 16) mod 16)), 16 * (Block mod 8) + (Index mod 16))

So global index is

128*128*(16 * (Block div 64) + (Index div 256)) + 128 * (16 * ((Block div 8) mod 8) + ((Index div 16) mod 16)) + 16 * (Block mod 8) + (Index mod 16)